# PANDAS in Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

I have looked at other threads about this topic, and so far I haven't had any luck.

I am trying to use pyinstaller to create an .exe that validates data. I can successfully create an executable, and it will run, but the pandas part of the code isn't working. I have attempted to download the development version of pyinstaller (which some say fixes this problem), but python isn't recognizing the development version of pyinstaller. I may be installing it wrong, but any help getting pandas to work in pyinstaller would be much appreciated!

Comment: Post your error message

Comment: smci, what would be the best way to capture the errors if my executable has a gui (tkinter)?

Comment: Well tell us as many key words from the error message as you can. Is it an installation error (offtopic on SO), import error, path error, some functional error...?